# Group by the content of array of string with out order in mongo aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, grouping

i have a problem with aggregation framework in MongoDB (mongoose) this is the problem. i have the following database scheme.so what i want to do is count number of people who has access through `Mobile` only , `Card` only, or both. with out any order,

```
  {
       '_id': ObjectId,
       'user_access_type': ['Mobile' , 'Card']
   }
    {
       '_id': ObjectId,
       'user_access_type': ['Card' , 'Mobile']
   }
    {
       '_id': ObjectId,
       'user_access_type': ['Mobile']
   }
  {
       '_id': ObjectId,
       'user_access_type': ['Card']
   }
```

Now i am using this but it only groups by the order of the `user_access_type` array,

```
[ { "$group" : {   "_id": {"User" : "$user_access_type"} ,   "count": {"$sum" : 1}   }]
```

this is the output:

```
{
            "_id": {
                "User": [
                    "Card",
                    "Mobile"
                ]
            },
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "_id": "5f7dce2359aaf004985f98eb",
                "User": [
                    "Mobile",
                    "Card"
                ]
            },
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "User": [
                    "Mobile"
                ]
            },
            "count": 1
        },
        
        {
            "_id": {
                "User": [
                    "Card"
                ]
            },
            "count": 1
        },
```

vs what i want:

```
  {
            "_id": {
                "User": [
                    "Card",
                    "Mobile"     // we can say both
                ]
            },
            "count": 2     // does not depend on order
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "User": [
                    "Mobile"
                ]
            },
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "User": [
                    "Card"
                ]
            },
            "count": 1
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use other option as well using `$function`,

- `$function` can allow to add `javascript` code, you can use `sort()` to sort the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      user_access_type: {
        $function: {
          body: function(user_access_type){
              return user_access_type.sort();
          },
          args: ["$user_access_type"],
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user_access_type",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

---

Second option,

If `user_access_type` array having always unique elements then you can use `$setUnion` operator on `user_access_type` array as self union, some how this will re-order array in same order,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      user_access_type: {
        $setUnion: "$user_access_type"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user_access_type",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BZJTYN6y_mq)